# Jenkins and running rake tasks

Tags: ruby, jenkins, docker, rake

I'm having some issues running a rake task from within Jenkins (within a docker container) as part of a build process (I have the Rake plugin installed). I am getting the error

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "rake" (in directory "/var/jenkins/workspace/HendricksFeaturesCopy"): error=2, No such file or directory
```

Which i don't understand as when i `pwd $ECHO` before the rake task is invoked i get.

```
/var/jenkins/workspace/HendricksFeaturesCopy
```

So i'm in the correct place and `rake` is installed as its located here

```
/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/rake
```

My `Rakefile` looks like

```
import 'lib/tasks/yard-docs.rake'
```

`lib/tasks/yard-docs.rake`

```
require 'yard'
namespace :yard_docs do

  desc 'Generate Yard Documentation'
  task :generate do
    # Generate Yard Documentation
  end
end
```

Does anyone know how to rectify this or what I am missing?

UPDATE

After doing `echo $PATH`

```
/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin
```

So this means the correct gemset is being used and when I have done `rvm @global do gem list`

```
rake (10.4.2)
```

So, rake is available right ?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure `/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/` is in your $PATH.

```
PATH=/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/:$PATH
```

Alternatively, symlink `/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/rake` to `/usr/local/bin/`

```
ln -s /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/rake /usr/local/bin/
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, i checked $PATH and it seems to be there, so is symlinking the way to go here ?

Comment: Just to be clear, you echo $PATH from within the Jenkins container right? What's the output of `type -a rake` and `which -a rake`?

Comment: yes echo $PATH was run in the container and output is `/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/rake`

Comment: You could try running `docker exec -it jenkins_container rake --version` to make sure the user running the jenkins process has access to it. It's also possible that the RUBY_HOME parameter isn't configured properly in Jenkin's configuration.

Comment: I get 'rpc error: code = 2 desc = "oci runtime error: exec failed: exec: \"rake\": executable file not found in $PATH"MC-S102486:, what i find myself doing though in my build process is `source /usr/local/rvm/scripts/rvm` to initialise rvm ??

Comment: RUBY_HOME can be found with `echo $RUBY_HOME` ?

Comment: I now get the error `usr/bin/env: ‘ruby’: No such file or directory` when runnning a rake task, the task runs as `usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/rake yard_docs:generate`. Im not entirely sure what to set as RUBY_HOME, `/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.3.0/bin/ruby` returns no such file or directory.. any ideas please ?